# Is using .done synonymous with async: false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I've got a whole bunch of $.ajax requests that need to wait for each other before firing off.  I'm aware that the async : false option is deprecated and I also know that if I stick subsequent functions in .done, then this will behave the same way as async : false.  To keep things clean, however, I'm wondering if as an alternative, I can just leave .done without additional code and just order my ajax from "top to bottom": Would this tell jquery to run the ajax, *then* perform whatever is in .done (nothing in my case!), "mimicking" async : false?

As an example:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        data: cool_data : "cool_data",
        url: 'somewhere_over_the_rainbow.php'
        }).done(function(){

        })
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        data: more_cool_data : "more_cool_data",
        url: 'more_somewhere_over_the_rainbow.php'
        }).done(function(){

        })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`done` registers a callback that will be called when the server answers.

Using `async:false` blocks the page until the server answers. **Don't use it**.

A solution to chain your calls is to use [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) :

```
$.ajax({ ... })
.then($.ajax({ ... })
.then($.ajax({ ... })
.then(function() { ... finished! ... });
```

Comment: Thank you for *finally* clearing up these differences.

Comment: Note that it's not specific to jQuery : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks for the additional link!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `complete` function?

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        data: cool_data : "cool_data",
        url: 'somewhere_over_the_rainbow.php',
        complete: function()
        {
            $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                data: more_cool_data : "more_cool_data",
                url: 'more_somewhere_over_the_rainbow.php',
                complete: function() 
                { 
                    // do something else
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: OP knew that, I think. His problem is : *"a whole bunch of $.ajax requests [...] To keep things clean"*

Comment: I've thought about that, but with 20 or so ajax calls, it looked like the nesting would get a bit out of hand.